# Where do I find a Silverlight browsing-control like this?

Tags: silverlight

I was wondering if there is a 3rd party control that allows something like this.

[image]

highly appreciated,
Kave

Comment: What you are looking for is either a coverflow or perhaps (less likely) a carousel control. Pretty much all of the major suppliers (Telerik, Infragistics, etc.) have these.

Comment: Thanks Chris, is there also free control available? Perhaps some toolkit etc?  But thanks for telling me the name, now I got an idea...

Comment: I found it here http://silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com/ Chris please answer the question instead of a comment, so that I can close the question lol :)

Comment: Another alternative: http://3dimagecarousel.codeplex.com/

Comment: @Brad: That has a GPL so it would be fine as long as the application its being used in is also released under GPL.  The silverlightcoverflow on the hand is under Ms-PL so can be used in a commercial app.

Comment: @Kave: Its ok for you to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it here silverlightcoverflow.codeplex.com